# JWPLAYER 6 Popout Currently Playing Item In New Window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video, jwplayer

I've created dynamic playlists through javascript so basically the user can click on buttons to change the playlist (eg : http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists)  and i've added the jwplayer code onto a specific div on the page , as below .

```
<div id="JW6DIV">
  <div id="video"></div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      jwplayer('container').setup({
        'width': "100%",,
        'file': "playlist1.mp4",
      });
  </script>
</div>

Now what i'm trying to do is have a popout button so that ONLY THE PLAYER would open up on a new window , so for that i've done the following to popout the DIV Of the Player ...

<script>
function openWin() {
    var divText = document.getElementById("JW6DIV").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=900,height=600');
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();
}
</script>

 <a href="#" onclick="openWin()">Popout Video</a>
```

Now this works , but it always returns the first playlist item , Basically the default one which appears when the page is opened , so if a user  has switched the playlist to anything other than "Playlist1.mp4" it wont matter because Only Playlist1.mp4 appears on the video when it pops up .

How can i accomplish this in a way that when a user switches the playlist and clicks on popout the playlist thats currently playing appears on the popout?

All help is greatly appreciated , been working on this for hours.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: i got a step closer by creating a variable for the currently active playlist item , so i would think i need to pass a function onto the Window calling a JW Player with the Variable , but it doesnt work :( . Any help guys?